# Showing three XMLs on a html page

Tags: html, xml

I want to show three XMLs on a single html page. These XMLs have XSLs associated with them.

Somthing like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do so? If yes, how?

P.S.: I'm using Windows XP SP3.

Comment: What server platform are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many solutions to do this:

- Use Ajax to get the xml file (as a string) and then do whatever you want with it.
- Use an `iframe` with `Content-Type: text/xml`
- [Use javascript](http://www.webreference.com/js/tips/020116.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use html/xhtml div tags to devide the page. Into sections you described above.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div height="20%" width="100%">xml1</div>
<div height="80%" width="20%" style="float:left;">xml2</div>
<div height="80%" width="80%" style="float:left;">xml3</div>
</body>
</html>
```